# getInstalledApplications vs getInstalledPackages

Tags: android

May I know what the differences between `getInstalledApplications` and `getInstalledPackages`? The documentation doesn't say much.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- [PackageManager.getInstalledApplications(int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications(int)) will provide you information regarding the AndroidManifest's `Application` tag, and just about it. Forget about activities, receivers, services and go on.
- [PackageManager.getInstalledPackages(int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages(int)), on the other hand, will provide you information regarding **all** AndroidManifest's elements, such as declared activities, services, receivers, meta-data

Both methods will provide info regarding whatever application, regardless they have or they have not declared an `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` intent category in some activity.

In addition, both methods will retrieve one PackageInfo/ApplicationInfo per APK, or being more specific, for package name.

Answer (score 3):

I think the term "`Application`" refers here to "Startable by the user" / Appears on the launcher.
This means, there are
a) Packages which are not executable directly (example: "DRM content", "Google Partner Setup" or "Market Updater" on my sgs2) .
b) Packages which provide multiple `Application`. Yes you heared right. One package could have multiple Applications - two launcher entries with icons. That's possible if you mark two or more Activities in your manifest.xml as `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering what the difference is between an application package, and a package in the documentation of getInstalledApplications and getInstalledPackages. So I guess packages are supersets of applications.

Comment: @user1118764 Please mark the answer "as answer" by clicking the green tick on the left side if it is. :)

Comment: It sounds like a very speculative answer not backed by any research/knowledge or just looking into the code of the both methods...

Comment: It is not, I can assure you :)

Comment: Well it starts from "I think" which sounds speculative as you don't know that for sure. Can you provide a reference to where this behaviour is described or documented or at least a reference to implementation. Sorry but for me the answer 2 sounds as more likely the case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23134675/501940

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The implementation of getInstalledApplications and getInstalledPackages is nearly identical, it's just a matter of whether you get back a list of ApplicationInfo or PackageInfo objects.